# couchdb find function with string comparison does not work as expected

Tags: find, couchdb, string-comparison

[image]

as you can see in the image i am querying a date string d_lastOpened against d_updated. The goal is to show all that where updated after lastOpened, that means d_lastOpened <= d_updated. Why is the 2. entry of the search result shown when it clearly does not fit that criteria?

i tried swapping fields around and using $gte but that does not work at all, which is logical.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a string comparison between the strings `"d_updated"` and the values for `d_lastOpened`, starting with `"2022"`.

`"2022" < "d"`, therefore the `"$lte"` comparison returns the two results, but `"$gte"` fails.

Comment: damn it, now that you mention it... i would like to compare the 2 fields not the string. is this possible? i dont see a example in couchdb doc. alternativley i could make a view for this